# Tree traversal in QML, checking if QModelIndex isValid

Tags: qt, treeview, qml, model-view

In order to expand the nodes of a TreeView to show the currently selected item (set by a shared selection model) I need to call TreeView.expand(QModelIndex) recursively.

```
    expand(index)
    expand(index.parent)
    expand(index.parent.parent)
    ...
```

this could be done by a function like this:

```
 function autoExpand(index ) {
    print(index)
    var oneUp = index

    do {

        print(oneUp)
        oneUp = index.parent
        expand(oneUp)
        print("do")
        print(oneUp)
    } while (oneUp)

}
```

however I don't know how to check for the root node. I tried

```
 while (oneUp)  -> always true
 while (oneUp.isValid) -> undefined ie always false
 while (oneUp.isValid()) -> property isValid cannot be called as a function
```

, in c++ it would be:

```
do {
   //....
} while (oneUp.isValid());
```

but I cannot find an equivalent function in QML (and don't know where to look for the code ...)

As a workaround I check it in c++ in an object that is already exported but well, it doesn't look proper:

```
public slots:
   bool indexIsValid(const QModelIndex &index) const {return index.isValid();}
```

Comment: This doesn't work? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-treeview.html#expand-method

Comment: It does work ... but it will not expand parent nodes as well. That's why I have to traverse the tree upwards and expand every parent node as well

Comment: Have you tried to track the root element first when it's added? And then compare with that.

Comment: It's always there and not typically exposed by the QAbstractItemModel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a side-effect of zizix's copy-paste answer I learned that the QModelIndex::isValid function translates to the index.valid property (?) in QML. Using that I can now successfully detect the root of a tree in QML:

```
function autoExpand(index ) {
        var oneUp = index

        do {
            oneUp = oneUp.parent
            expand(oneUp)                
        } while (oneUp.valid);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

"...\Qt\5.5\Src\qtquickcontrols\src\controls\TreeView.qml"

```
function expand(index) {
        if (index.valid && index.model !== model)
            console.warn("TreeView.expand: model and index mismatch")
        else
            modelAdaptor.expand(index)
    }
```

Comment: Source code is available here: https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols.git/tree/src/controls/TreeView.qml